# Как сделать скриншот видео игры в Full Screen Mode из .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-8

Каким образом можно сделать (максимально эффективно) скриншот из видео игры которая может находиться как в `Full Screen Mode` так и в `Window Fullscreen Mode` из `.NET` программы?

Под максимальной эффективностью подразумевается, с использованием минимальных ресурсов `CPU` компьютера.

P.S. Необходимо делать скриншот 1 раз скажем, каждые 10 секунд, и что бы при этом не напрягать процессор.